# Dbunit xmlfile fubctions for autogenerating ids

Tags: java, spring, dbunit

I have a problem with DBUnit in my testc cases. When I create my data in db unit I currently explicitly specify Ids. It looks something like this.

```
  <users user_id="35" corpid="CORP\35" last_login="2014-10-27 00:00:00.0" login_count="1" is_manager="false"/>
  <plans plan_id="18332" state="1" owned_by_user="35" revision="4"/>
  <plan_history plan_history_id="12307" date_created="2014-08-29 14:40:08.356" state="0" plan_id="18332"/>
  <plan_history plan_history_id="12308" date_created="2014-08-29 16:40:08.356" state="1" plan_id="18332"/>
  <goals goal_id="12331" goal_name="Dansa" description="Dans"/>
  <personal_goals plan_id="18332" personal_goal_id="18338" date_finished="2014-10-28 00:00:00.192" goal_id="12331" state="0"/>
  <personal_goal_history personal_goal_id="18338" personal_goal_history_id="18005" date_created="2014-08-29 14:40:08.356" state="1" />
  <activities activity_id="13001"/>
  <custom_activities activity_name="customActivity" description="Replace" activity_id="13001"/>
  <personal_activities personal_activity_id="17338"  personal_goal_id="18338" date_finished="2014-10-28 00:00:00.192" state="0"  activity_id="13000"/>
  <personal_activity_history personal_activity_id="17338" personal_activity_history_id="18338" date_created="2014-08-29 14:40:29.073" state="1" />
```

Since the id of the user is specified literally we often get merge problems between tests and they are really cumbersome to solve. This is because we may be working on different branches and several people may have allocated the same ids. The solution then becomes updating all ids in the seed data and all relational ids as well as updating the test-files. This work is really cumbersome.

Im there for looking for some way to autogenerate ids. For instance functions like `getNextId("User")` and `getLatestId("User")` would be of great help. Is there something like this in DB unit or could I myself some how create such functions?

If there are other suggestions to how this problem can be avoided Id gladly here them as well.

Comment: What does "merge problems between tests" mean?

Comment: It means when we are adding tests in different branches of our vsc system  (git) we have problems when trying to merge our seed data file. This is because when we have to give the ids of a specific user for a specific test we have to make certain that no one else has used that id in their tests on their branches. As that is really hard to do for large teams we now some times have to renumber both the id:s in the test and the ones in the seed data if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using same test data file for all tests.  It is better practice to have multiple test files - one per test for its test specific data and common files used for "master list" data.  The "master list" data does not change per test, thereby not encountering the mentioned problem when merging test data files.

Comment: I agree splitting the test data should probably work.